# My server is not responding, it is hanging up, did not returning anything

Tags: python, django, docker, face-recognition

I have a docker image successfully built on my mac. I am running this image by typing docker run -p 8000:8000 .
Django server is up and ready to accept requests. but when I request to given URL via postman I am getting an error: socket hangs up.
Here is my docker file.

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-stretch
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN cd ~ && \
    mkdir -p dlib && \
    git clone -b 'v19.9' --single-branch https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git dlib/ && \
    cd  dlib/ && \
    python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
RUN pip3 install --default-timeout=100 future
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD python3 manage.py makemigrations face && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver
```

The browser also responding by the server didn't send data.
Please help me.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your code too. For all we know, your server code hangs up on purpose.

Comment: You shouldn't have `makemigrations` in your CMD, by the way.

Comment: how can i modify my question

Comment: You have to listen to the IP `0.0.0.0`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `runserver` command listens on 127.0.0.1 (the loopback interface) by default, since it's meant for development, not production.

In order for something to be `-p`ublishable from a Docker container to the outside world, it needs to listen on `0.0.0.0`, i.e. all interfaces.

Add that to your `runserver` invocation...

```
CMD python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```